# Add to cart button border

Tags: css

please I have got below CSS to change mobile add to cart button background to gold color

```
.add-to-cart-wrap .button::before {
  background:gold !important;
}
```

I'd like to make the border color "purple". Thanks

Comment: We need more code

Comment: It doesn't work, see the add to cart button in question in this screenshot prnt.sc/nXE8RBlXUNEa I had want it with a purple border site

Comment: Thanks a lot, but still not working

Comment: I used this .add-to-cart-wrap .button::before{
background: gold; 
border: 1px solid purple;
} and it works

Comment: This has been resolved. Thanks

Comment: This has been resolved. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This solution does what you need:

`.add-to-cart-wrap .button {background-color: gold; border: 1px solid purple;}`

Comment: It doesn't work, see the add to cart button in question in this screenshot https://prnt.sc/nXE8RBlXUNEa
I had want it with a purple border site

Comment: Hey @OlufemiOdunfa, I'm a bit confused. Do u mean u want a rounded button with golden background color and a purple border?

Comment: This has been resolved. Thanks

Comment: Oh, Alright. That's great.

Answer (score 0):

If button is a standalone element then you can try this.

**Update example**
As you can see here it works, you just have to figure out if you have other css selectors affecting your button, in that case use them to change the css.

```css
.button {
background: gold; 
border: 1px solid purple;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
border-radius: 100px;
}
```

```html
<button class="button">Cart</button>
```

```
.button {
   background: gold !important; 
   border: 1px solid purple;
}
```

Otherwise, if button is a class belonging to the tag that contains .add-to-cart-wrap then try this

```
.add-to-cart-wrap.button {
   background: gold !important; 
   border: 1px solid purple;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, see the add to cart button in question in this screenshot prnt.sc/nXE8RBlXUNEa I had want it with a purple border site

Comment: Have you tried to apply !Important also to the border? Maybe you already have a css that defines the border. So try applying !Important to the border.

Comment: Yes, I applied ! important and no effect

Comment: Can you put the whole css and html code so that you have a clearer idea? Or the project link if you can...

Comment: This has been resolved. Thanks